# Show that $b^{2^n}+1$ is a factor of $b^{2^m}-1$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $m$ and $n$ be natural numbers such that $m>n$ and $b$ be any integer

Show that $b^{2^n}+1$ is a factor of  $b^{2^m}-1$.

Comment: Three people had already answered your original question. Then the question was edited to an entirely new one. I have rolled back.

Comment: Fine, I asked the first one mistakenly. Wont happen again. Sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to use the fact that $a^{2}-1=(a-1)(a+1)$,
$$b^{2^{m}}-1=(b^{2^{m-1}}-1)(b^{2^{m-1}}+1)=(b^{2^{m-2}}-1)(b^{2^{m-2}}+1)(b^{2^{m-1}}+1)$$$$=...=(b^{2^n}-1)\prod_{i=0}^m (b^{2^{n+i}}+1)$$

Answer (score 0):

We have $b^{2^{n+1}}-1 = (b^{2^n}+1)(b^{2^n}-1)$. Hence, $b^{2^n} \pm 1$ divides $b^{2^{n+1}}-1$. Now use induction to conclude what you want.